# Openshift - 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable when i am accessing the app

Tags: node.js, openshift, paas

I got an app hosted on Openshift [here](https://news-mithunsatheesh.rhcloud.com/) , using node.js and mongo db. It was running perfectly yesterday and today when i am accessing the same, i am getting

Service Temporarily Unavailable Error

I searched some threads and tried this command

```
rhc tail -a news
```

and result was

> npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20 npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.37 npm ERR! code
>
> ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! message OpenShift-Sample-App@1.0.0 start: `node
>
> server.js`npm ERR! message`sh "-c" "node server.js"` failed with 1
>
> npm ERR! npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in: npm ERR!
>
> /var/lib/openshift/4eb0c449f78a4d7e937726185b5e636e/app-root/runtime/repo/npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! not ok code undefined npm ERR! not ok code 1

I have also tried

```
rhc app status -a news
```

and result was

> RESULT: Geargroup nodejs-0.6+mongodb-2.2 is started

also i tried to restart my app

```
rhc app restart
```

and it restarted properly.
Could you suggest me what is the issue.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by [Hardy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115835/hardy), i still dont know which resource got exceeded. But have fixed it now.

Here is what i did.

1. just get remote access to your app console as described [here](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/remote-access).
2. ssh into the console with a client like PuTTy or Cygwin.
3. just check the status of your app by typing `ctl_app status`. for me it came like : 
   **App is currently inaccessible or stopped.**
4. just start it by typing `ctl_all start`

Now app is working as previously.

Comment: m having exactly same issue... ctl_all start says started but i again call ctl_app status : says stopped. One more thing, logs says.. "auth fails" on mongodb connection, whereas i have provided exact connection url as given by openshift. Copy-paste.. so no chance of typos.

Comment: Yea good idea. rhc says its mine's running but ctl_app says otherwise. Logs show app errors with the config which is stopping the app running. Fixing and starting the app fixed it for me.  Checking the logs is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a free OpenShift account (free grear)? If so, what is your app doing? Is it very CPU or memory intensive. Your gears are monitored using cgroups and once you exceed any resource limit (cpu, memory, threads) your app gets killed. In this case you would get the message you describe. Unfortunately there is no way of telling which resource you exceeded and you don't get a notification that this was the problem. At least that is something I experienced with my apps. Of course there could be other problems with your app.

Comment: Its now fixed.. I just configured ssh access and restarted the app

Comment: This is incorrect. Killing only occurs if the app exceeds memory limits; oom_killer picks a process to kill. If your app only has one process (and lots of threads) then your app is dead in the water until watchman restarts it. If (as with httpd-based carts like php) it's just one process of many, you'll hardly notice. Exceeding CPU just gets CPU throttled. Exceeding procs/threads/storage limits means you'll see failures trying to access those things.